# iptables -L pretty slow. Is this normal?

Tags: linux, iptables

Quick question but Gooling has not revealed an answer. When I do `iptables -L`, it seems to lag on displaying items in where I have limited the source to internal ips `192.168.0.0/24`

The whole listing takes about 30 seconds to display.

I just want to know: Does this affect the speed of my incoming connections or is this simply a side effect of having all these ranges within my iptables rules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Include the -n option so it doesn't try to use DNS to resolve names for every ip address, network and port.  Then it will be fast.

Comment: I generally like `iptables -vnL --line-numbers` for my listing command.  Keep in mind by default you don't see all the tables, for instance, the nat table.  To see that nat table: `-t nat`

Comment: `-t mangle` & `-t raw` also are not displayed by default

Answer (score 1):

For me it was slow and also I was getting this error

```
sudo: unable to resolve host selleraz-proxy-service: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I add

```
127.0.0.1   machine-hostname
```

to /etc/hosts 
It worked so well like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I've personally seen this happen on a server that was configured for LDAP authentication, but could not reach the LDAP server (this was SLED 10).  In my case, "netstat -a" and "iptables -L" were both exhibiting the same behavior you describe.  An "strace" of the netstat showed it hanging on a connection to port 636 (LDAP-Secure).  Turning off the LDAP (which, for me, was not needed on this platform) fixed the problem.